# SQL запрос: Выборка в таблице по двум полям с двумя столбцами. Как?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть таблица:

[image: Текст]

Необходимо получить post_id где колонка name=ExtractFiles и колонка status=none, плюс колонка name=DownloadFromFileHosting и колонка status=ок

В нашем случае получим post_id номер 133

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT post_id FROM your_table WHERE name='ExtractFiles' AND status='none' 
UNION
SELECT post_id FROM your_table WHERE name='DownloadFromFileHosting' AND status='ok'
```

Comment: Лучше `UNION ALL`, чтобы исключить излишнюю в данном случае операцию удаления дублей, которых гарантированно не будет.

Comment: Запрос даст "ИЛИ", хотя автору нужно "И". *дублей, которых гарантированно не будет.* Угу... первый подзапрос вернёт упомянутое автором 133, и второй тоже... как по мне, так это дубль.

Comment: Спасибо, запрос работает если ставить лимит на выборку один и если гарантировано есть хоть одно id с такими условиями, если без лимита то вытягивает все id с такими условиями, и еще если допустим нет id со статусом 'none' а все со статусом 'ok' , то вытягивает самый первый по порядку по лимиту.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT post_id
FROM sourcetable
WHERE (name, status) IN ( ('ExtractFiles', 'none'),
                          ('DownloadFromFileHosting', 'ok') )
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name, status) = 2
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name, status) = 2' at line 5

Comment: я обратил внимание на скобки, добавил закрывающуюся, запрос работает но дает пустой результат

Comment: @ultralaise Сделайте fiddle со структурой и данными, и покажите, где, как и на чём получается "пустой результат".

Comment: Ура сработало!!! Вы дали правильную наводку, немного подредактировал запрос, и получилось: SELECT post_id
FROM tasks
WHERE (name, status) IN ( ('ExtractFiles','none'), ('DownloadFromFileHosting','ok') )
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(1)=2
ORDER BY post_id ASC
LIMIT 1

Comment: @ultralaise *HAVING COUNT(1)=2* Только если  имеется уникальный индекс `(post_id, name)`. Иначе - это явная ошибка. PS. Давно бы уже пора указать хотя бы СУБД (ещё лучше - включая версию), неверный результат может быть и следствием особенностей синтаксиса.

Answer (score 0):

Можно объединить таблицу саму с собой по post_id, а потом из одной взять записи по вашему первому условию, а из второй - по второму. В пересечении окажутся нужные идешки.

Тестовые данные:

```
create table foo (post_id int, name char(8), status char(10))
select 1 post_id, 'name-1-1' name, 'status-1-1' status union
select 1 post_id, 'name-1-2' name, 'status-1-2' status union
select 2 post_id, 'name-2-1' name, 'status-2-1' status union
select 2 post_id, 'name-2-2' name, 'status-2-2' status union
select 3 post_id, 'name-3-1' name, 'status-3-2' status
```

И запрос вида:

```
select f1.post_id
from foo f1
inner join foo f2 using(post_id)
where f1.name = 'name-1-1'
  and f1.status = 'status-1-1'
  and f2.name = 'name-1-2'
  and f2.status = 'status-1-2'
```

.. найдёт post_id = 1. Подставьте свои значения в where и получите то что нужно.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d50dc/1